# Inherit self from another class file

Tags: python

How could a class inherit from another class in a separate file the instance self.
I am working on the following example, here is the first file
called IniState.py​

```
class importdata():

    def Thresholds(self):

        # Seuils definis pour le vent
        # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.var1 = 1.5
        self.var2  = 7.5
        self.var3  = 5.

        self.var4   = 80.
        self.var5   = 135.
        self.var6   = 110.

        self.var7   = 8.
        self.var8   = 35.
        self.var9   = 10.
```

and the second file called main.py contains the following class

```
from IniState import importdata

class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        importdata().Thresholds()


    def variable(self):
        print self.var1
        print self.var2
        print self.var7​



if __name__ == '__main__':
    use().tri()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use `self` instead of delegating the call you need to inherit the second class from the first one for that to work.

```
class Foo(importdata):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.Thresholds()
```

Now, does it makes sense to use inheritance over delegation or not, that depends on what the actual classes are and what they do. Also, please try to follow variable conventions of Python.